# Coalesce two columns with a condition in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, coalesce

I would like to coalesce two columns to remove all NA but at the same time where both columns have values I would like to keep only the highest value.

Example:

```
df <- data.frame(A = c(1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,NA),
                 B = c(0,NA,1,1,NA,1,0,1,1))

   A  B
1  1  0
2  0 NA
3  1  1
4  0  1
5  1 NA
6  1  1
7  0  0
8  0  1
9 NA  1
```

wanted result

```
   A  B C
1  1  0 1
2  0 NA 0
3  1  1 1
4  0  1 1
5  1 NA 1
6  1  1 1
7  0  0 0
8  0  1 1
9 NA  1 1
```

Comment: `do.call(pmax, c(df, na.rm = TRUE))`

Comment: `+!!rowSums(df, na.rm = TRUE)` if your columns are all 0/1s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate rowwise maximum removing `NA` values:

```
matrixStats::rowMaxs(as.matrix(df), na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1
```

Or with `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(C = max(c_across(), na.rm = TRUE))

#     A     B     C
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     0     1
#2     0    NA     0
#3     1     1     1
#4     0     1     1
#5     1    NA     1
#6     1     1     1
#7     0     0     0
#8     0     1     1
#9    NA     1     1
```

Comment: great thanks! is "c_across" really necessary? It seems to work fine with only across.

Comment: Yes, that would work but `across` is used for columnwise operations. When using with `rowwise` it is better to use `c_across` since it is designed for that.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `reduce` with `pmax`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>% 
    mutate(C = reduce(., pmax, na.rm = TRUE))
```

-output

```
#   A  B C
#1  1  0 1
#2  0 NA 0
#3  1  1 1
#4  0  1 1
#5  1 NA 1
#6  1  1 1
#7  0  0 0
#8  0  1 1
#9 NA  1 1
```